# Access the data passed by a JSON File in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

The following code is working fine...

```
  const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState();
  async function pullJson() {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const responseData = await response.json();
    displayData = responseData.map((el) => {
      return <p key={el.id}>{el.title}</p>;
    });
    setShowPosts(displayData);
  }
```

if i use {showPosts} in the "return" part, it will display a series of paragraph's with the "id" and the "title" values of the JSON BUT... I would like to navigate in the JSON data and access any value I want... so my idea was the following...

```
  const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState();
  async function pullJson() {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const responseData = await response.json();
    setShowPosts(responseData);
  }
```

Now if I try to access {showPosts[12]} or {showPosts[12].id} I get an error like :
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userId, id, title, completed}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I know that objects are not valid as a react child...  buut here, I have an array of object, I select and index (12) where my object is, and call an existing key (id) of this object.. Why does it throw this error... :s :s :s  Thanks for your help !!

1. I have tried to define my useState variable like an array..

```
const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState([]);
```

It doesn't work

2. I have tried to define my useState variable like an array containing a default object

```
  const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState([
    {
      userId: 1111,
      id: 1111,
      title: "delectus aut autem",
      completed: false,
    },
  ]);
```

Here it is strange... after the setShowPosts(displayData); which sets the state to the array of all my objects defined in the JSON, i'm able to call {showPosts[0].id}, but if i try to call the others like {showPosts[1].id} or {showPosts[2].id} i get an error : Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: Since you have an array of objects and all objects are sitting on position 0 i.e showPosts[0].id that's why you have an error of cannot read properties of undefined.

Comment: Why do you say all objects are on position 0 ? When I do setShowPosts(responseData); showPosts is like [{ .... }, { .... }, { .... }, { .... }, ....]

Comment: all objects are in position zero, because objects are adding more and more, not the array's position. Array's are like [1,2,3] , now think of all your objects are placing like this : [{.....},2,3]

Comment: I've made some console.log... ...It is not the case... ...I think it is more a problem useState... ...but I dont understand, because I do a useEffect first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: I’d search for all the usages of `showPosts` and make sure they have been changed to `showPosts[index]?.id`. If element at `index` doesn’t exist on `showPosts` you would get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`. This could happen if `showPosts` is initialized to an empty array, since it would be empty until the fetch completes.

You could either use optional chaining `showPosts[index]?.id` or do something like `showPosts.map(post => id)`.

—-

It looks like `responseData` has the following structure `[ { id: string, title: string } ]`, so it’s a JSON array of objects where each object has an `id` an a `title`.

In your first code snippet, `responseData`  is converted from an array of JSON objects to an array of JSX `<p>` tags:

```
displayData = responseData.map((el) => {
          return <p key={el.id}>{el.title}</p>;  })
```

`displayData` can then be inserted anywhere in JSX document using `{{showPosts}}`, since it is also JSX.

In you second code snippet, `showPosts` is now an array of JSON objects and React cannot render JSON objects. So when React tries to render the individual objects in the `showPosts` array you get `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userId, id, title, completed}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Also in your second scenario `showPosts` is initialized to empty array, so an empty array will be rendered until data is returned from `fetch` (which might take a few seconds). When you try to access element at index 12 of this empty array this element would be undefined (since the array has 0 elements), and you cannot read property `id` of an undefined object. Optional chaining or [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) can be used here to only access `id` when an element at index 12 exists.